# Retrieve old files from parse.com migration?

Tags: mongodb, heroku, parse-platform

I recently walked through migration and after changing the code in my app delegate file in swift to my new Heroku/Mongo setup I can't access old files for my app. It appears my images, etc. were not brought over. Any way to fix that?

Thanks, I have tried looking through questions to find relevant answers, to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

you should lookup the fileKey in your parse.com app (security/keys) and than add it to new parse server and add it as a config var.

See: [Access denied to files after migration from parse.com to heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37622580/access-denied-to-files-after-migration-from-parse-com-to-heroku)